# Restored Wordpress on new Server - Can't auto-update plugins

Tags: plugins, ftp, automatic-updates

I have installed a new Ubuntu server and have set everything up for Wordpress.
I have also extracted mySite directory in the /var/www/ and did a 
`mysql -u mysqlusername -p databasename < blog.bak.sql` to restore the data to the database.

It all worked smooth and works beautifully.

The only problem I have discovered is when I try to auto-update the plugins.

Please click to see the screenshot (I don't have enough reputation to insert a screenshot here)
http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/970/76811016.png

Well, I have never setup any FTP on my previous server. How comes this is now asking me this information? And yes I was able to auto-update plugs on my other server without a problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because of file permissions on your server. WordPress needs to be able to write to the `wp-content` folder. I highly suggest you read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) about changing file permissions for WordPress.

You may also need to CHOWN the directory that contains WordPress to the user that your web server uses. [More here.](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/why-wordpress-asks-connection-info/)

Comment: That was it. Thank you. :)  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/MySite

Comment: BTW, was it alright that I didn't restore the data into the database through the MySQL root user? I just picked the db user.

Comment: That should be fine, as long as that user has the necessary privileges to the database.